# How to construct a temporal network using python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, network-programming, networkx

I have a data for different stations at different days:

```
Station_start    Station_end    Day    Hour
A                B              1      14
B                C              1      10
C                A              1      10
B                A              2      15
A                C              2      13
D                E              2      12
E                B              2      14
F                C              3      12
```

I want to construct a dynamic/interactive network, where the network connections change according to day.

I found an example of it in the [tutorial of pathpy](https://www.pathpy.net/tutorial/temporal_nets.html).

But, How to load a pandas dataframe to it with nodes Station_start and Station_end?

Comment: for index, row in hour_data.iterrows():
        t.add_edge(row['start_station_name'], row['end_station_name'],row['hour'])

    print(t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do what you want. First, load your data into a pandas dataframe using `pd.read_fwf` (I saved your data in a file called `data_net.txt`).
Then incrementally add edges to your temporal network using `pp.add_edge`. Run `t` in a cell to see the animation.
See code below for more details:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pathpy as pp

df=pd.read_fwf('data_net.txt')

t = pp.TemporalNetwork()
[t.add_edge(df['Station_start'][i],df['Station_end'][i],int(df['Day'][i])) for i in range(len(df))]

t  # run t in a cell to start the animation
```

Below is what this code returns. Based on the link you gave, you can also control the speed of the animation by styling the network with pathpy.

[image]